# Spacing in the lines written in text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

If someone knows tkinter very well he will get what I am exactly asking.

I have a code where I am trying to see the impact of the option or you can say keyword of text widget named *spacing2*. I want to know why this option is used.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

txt = Text(root,spacing2 = 100)
txt.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Help me to know why this option or keyword named spacing2 is used here.

Comment: If you type in more than one line of text, it should be obvious what the option is doing - it adds space between lines of text (there is also `spacing1` to add space before the first line, and `spacing3` for space after the last line).

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation (e.g. [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text.html))

> This option specifies how much extra vertical space to add between
> displayed lines of text when a logical line wraps. Default is 0.

Here is an example that makes it quite obvious:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Text
root = Tk()

txt = Text(root, spacing2=10, wrap='word', width=10)
txt.insert('1.0', 'This is a very long line that is wrapped.')
txt.pack()
txt2 = Text(root, wrap='word', width=10)
txt2.insert('1.0', 'This is a very long line that is wrapped.')
txt2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]